# Simple debugger, want work?

Tags: python, debugging

i'm reading the Gray Hat Python,, i reach for this ::

```
class debugger():
    def __init__(self):
        self.h_process = None
        self.pid = None
        self.debugger_active = False

    def load(self,path_to_exe):
        creation_flags = DEBUG_PROCESS
        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
        process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION()
        startupinfo.dwFlags = 0x1
        startupinfo.wShowWindows = 0x0
        startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo)
        if kernel32.CreateProcessA(path_to_exe,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   creation_flags,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   byref(startupinfo),
                                   byref(process_information)):
            print "[*] We have successfully launched the process!"
            print "[*] PID: %d"%(process_information.dwProcessId)
            self.h_process = self.open_process(process_information.dwProcessId)

        else:
            print "[*] Error: 0x%08x."%(kernel32.GetLastError())

    def open_process(self,pid):
        h_process = self.open_process(pid)
        if kernel32.DebugActiveProcess(pid):
            self.debugger_active = True
            self.pid = int(pid)
            self.run()
        else:
            print "[*] Unable to attach to the process."

    def run(self):
        while self.debugger_active == True:
            self.get_debug_event()

    def get_debug_event(self):
        debug_event = DEBUG_EVENT()
        continue_status = DBG_CONTINUE
        if kernel32.WaitForDebugEvent(byref(debug_event), INFINITE):
            raw_input("Press a Key to continue...")
            self.debugger_active = False
            kernel32.ContinueDebugEvent( \
                debug_event.dwProcessId, \
                debug_event.dwThreadId, \
                continue_status )
    def detach(self):
        if kernel32.DebugActiveProcessStop(self.pid):
            print "[*] Finished debugging. Exiting..."
            return True
        else:
            print "There was an error"
            return False
```

when run my_test.py ::

```
import my_dbg

debugger = my_dbg.debugger()
pid = raw_input('Enter the PID of the process to attach to: ')
debugger.open_process(int(pid))
debugger.detach()
```

i get this error ::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/dbgpy/my_test.py", line 5, in <module>
    debugger.attach(int(pid))
  File "C:/Python26/dbgpy\my_dbg.py", line 37, in attach
    h_process = self.attach(pid)
  ...........
  ...........
  ...........
  File "C:/Python26/dbgpy\my_dbg.py", line 37, in attach
    h_process = self.attach(pid)
  File "C:/Python26/dbgpy\my_dbg.py", line 37, in attach
    h_process = self.attach(pid)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

its because the loop and something else, but what it is ??
I'm running on Windows using Python2.6.4.. :)

**Update::**

Found the problem thanks all,,
this code work great :)

```
from ctypes import *
from my_dbg_def import *
kernel32 = windll.kernel32
class debugger():
    def __init__(self):
        self.h_process = None
        self.pid = None
        self.debugger_active = False

    def open_process(self,pid):
        h_process = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,pid,False)
        return h_process

    def attach(self,pid):

        self.h_process = self.open_process(pid)

        if kernel32.DebugActiveProcess(pid):
            self.debugger_active = True
            self.pid = int(pid)

        else:
            print "[*] Unable to attach to the process."

    def run(self):
        while self.debugger_active == True:
            self.get_debug_event()

    def get_debug_event(self):
        debug_event = DEBUG_EVENT()
        continue_status= DBG_CONTINUE
        if kernel32.WaitForDebugEvent(byref(debug_event),INFINITE):
            raw_input("Press a key to continue...")
            self.debugger_active = False
            kernel32.ContinueDebugEvent( \
            debug_event.dwProcessId, \
            debug_event.dwThreadId, \
            continue_status )
    def detach(self):
        if kernel32.DebugActiveProcessStop(self.pid):
            print "[*] Finished debugging. Exiting..."
            return True
        else:
            print "There was an error"
            return False
```

Comment: You didn't paste the code to your attach method, where the recursion apparently occurs, so it's impossible to be of help.  Pls edit your Q to show that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose at a certain point, you changed name from attach to open_process (as it seems from the output of the traceback).
In this case, the error is here:

```
def open_process(self,pid): 
    h_process = self.open_process(pid)
```

As you can see, it is recursively calling itself.
It seems to me that you have it for some copy&paste, so maybe you can safely remove it.